# How to refresh a page to consider changes after an insert into the database in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm working on a WP8 app. I can display a list of items in my app without a problem. But when I update or insert a record into the database, I have to restart the app to see the changes. Otherwise, the list is the same as before the update.

My code:

```
private async Task<bool> InitOverdueList()
    {
        var orderList = await _ordersManagement.GetOverdueOrders();
        if (orderList == null)
        {
            _app.LoadingPopup.IsOpen = false;
            return false;
        }
        var templist = from c in orderList.Data orderby c.EstimatedEndDate, c.Id ascending select c;
        Overdue.Header = String.Format("Overdue ({0})", templist.Count());
        OverdueOrders.ItemsSource = templist.Select(o => new OrderItemViewModel(o));
        return true;
    }
```

How can I get my list to auto-update?

Answer (score 2):

For your requirement's solution you can use the [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) class object to bind your list control.

Hope it helps.

Comment: How can I deserialize a JSon in ObservableCollection? Due to RestSharp I'm forced to deserialize into a List

Comment: var observableOverdueOrders = new ObservableCollection<OverdueOrder>(orderList);